# Form element not setting the width correctly based on its contents

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a page similar to this, however the form width is not matching getting set to the required amount, but instead is spanning across the whole page:

[image: Sample Image]

I tried to do the following and cant get ahead.
https://jsfiddle.net/mrf3wL1q/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <!--menu-->
    </div>
 
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="group">
                <input type = "text" placeholder = "Your Name" id = "name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type = "email" placeholder = "Enter Your Email" id = "email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                    <input type = "password" placeholder = "Password" id = "password"/>
                    <input type = "password" placeholder = "Confirm Password" id = "password"/>
            </div>

                <div class="submit"><input id = "submit" type="submit" name= "formSubmit" value="CREATE A FREE ACCOUNT" class="btn"/></div>   
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.forms{
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
}
input{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
input#name{
    background-image: url(images/name.jpg);
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;
    border:none;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
}
input#email{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-image: url(images/mail.jpg);
    background-size: 7%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left 6px;
    border:none;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: :16px;
}
input#password{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url(images/pass.png);
    background-size: 7%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left 6px;
    border:none;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 4px; 
}

input#submit{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #A5ABB0;
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 447px;   
     cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;

}

.group{
    margin: 18px auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BEBEBE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have done the following changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrf3wL1q/

I've set the form container width to auto, however the form is not adjusting to its contents

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: Hi, "not working" is not a good error description. Please try to describe what exactly goes wrong, and consider building a test case on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: things like font size, automatic adjustment,etc of container are not working

Comment: Please at least build a test case.

Comment: @Md.MohsinHussain Check out my answer. You need to do a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost got it. You just need to give `width` and `margin` for the `<form>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <!--menu-->
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="group">
          <input type = "text" placeholder = "Your Name" id = "name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type = "email" placeholder = "Enter Your Email" id = "email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type = "password" placeholder = "Password" id = "password"/>
          <input type = "password" placeholder = "Confirm Password" id = "password"/>
        </div>

        <div class="submit"><input id = "submit" type="submit" name= "formSubmit" value="CREATE A FREE ACCOUNT" class="btn"/></div>   
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
body{
  background-image: url(images/bg.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #00f;
}
.container{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 125px auto 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.forms{
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}
input{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
input#name{
  background-image: url(images/name.jpg);
  background-size: 10%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  border:none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
}
input#email{
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(images/mail.jpg);
  background-size: 7%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left 6px;
  border:none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: :16px;
}
input#password{
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-image: url(images/pass.png);
  background-size: 7%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left 6px;
  border:none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 4px; 
}

input#submit{
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #A5ABB0;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 447px;   
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;

}

.group{
  margin: 18px auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #BEBEBE;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Output: http://jsbin.com/zorelitema**

Comment: isnt there any other way in which we dont have to hard code it to be at 50%, cant the width be changed automatically?

Comment: @Md.MohsinHussain To what width you wanna have. You need to give a width for sure.

Comment: why so?cant we make it in such a way that the width gets equal to the contents inside it automatically

Comment: @Md.MohsinHussain If you want that, you shouldn't give `width: auto` for `block` elements, which makes the `width` to be `100%`. Instead, set `display: inline-block` and give `width: auto`. Does it clarify?

Comment: oh cool, that worked. thanks ,btw why did we do this and how did it work

Comment: The `display: block` elements take full width. While `inline-block` takes only the width of the contents. That's the main difference.

Comment: ok. also there is this line joining password and confirm pass. i want to make it like that in the picture,any suggestions?

Comment: @Md.MohsinHussain You can give a `margin-right` `:)`

Comment: na not working. the thing is i have these two inputs in the same group ,therefore they have that continuous line. if make them in two different groups then they will be on the different line,i dont want that to happen

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to apply css on input area, then write selector as...

```
input[type="text"]
```

or

```
input [type="password"]
```

or

```
input [type="submit"]
```

-- if you facing another problem on css, please describe properly.... thx.

Comment: what should i do to make the page like the one i added in this post

Comment: also, how to make the size of container equal to its contents